# Dispersion relation from Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, tight-binding, bloch-oscillation

Note: This is obviously for homework so I'm not asking for the answer to be spoon fed, I'm just not understanding the steps I have to take.

I have a fairly simple Hamiltonian for a ring tight binding model

$$
H = \left( \begin{matrix}
    E_0+V_1  & -\gamma & 0   & 0   & \dots   & -\gamma \\
    -\gamma  & E_0+V_2 & -\gamma & 0   & \dots   & 0   \\
    0   & -\gamma & E_0+V_3 & -\gamma & \dots   & 0   \\
    &   &   & \ddots &    &   \\
    0   & \dots & 0    & -\gamma & E_0+V_{N-1} & -\gamma \\
    -\gamma  & \dots & 0    & 0   & -\gamma  & E_0+V_N \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

And I need to "Construct the eigenvectors of the translation operator from the eigenstates of $H$. Determine the Bloch value $k$ (actually $ka$) for each eigenvector.

After looking around online I don't understand what the translation operator or what Bloch values are.

Could someone either offer some hints or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you familiar with what the $d/dx$ looks like in matrix form?

Comment: Lanczos method?

Answer (score 1):

This wikipedia article sums up the translation matrix and bloch values so you at least know what you're looking for, ha. All the help I can give right now, good luck.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)#Discrete_Translation_in_Periodic_Potential:_Bloch.27s_Theorem